# How to remove hover color from cardview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the color of cardview when it is clicked

```
       card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cb_cardView);
        card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteFont));
        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AppNavigator(ActivityPlay.this).navigateToHome();
//hover color for car that goes to a new page when cliked
                card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

            }

        });
```

but the color does not change when I go back to this page.

Comment: the color should change. I doubt it's something related to the state of your UI. Are you doing this inside fragment or activity?

Comment: activity. it changes when clicked. I want to change it back when when it is not clicked

Comment: Can you try moving this line `card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));` before `new AppNavigator(ActivityPlay.this).navigateToHome();` ? I believe you are naviagted before.